# test failure when using VCR with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, paperclip, vcr

I have a test that works, and passes, the first time but fails the second time the spec suite is run:

```
  VCR.use_cassette("master_image_create_2", :match_requests_on => [:method, :uri]) do
      mi = Factory.build(:master_asset)
      img = File.new( File.join(Rails.root, "spec", "support", "fonzi.jpg") )
      mi.image = img
      mi.valid?
      mi.sha.should eql("f70393ee4d6e1f6a735df9526694e038371e5b3c")
      mi.url.to_s.include?("http://domain.com/test-brand/original-test-product_f_test-color-1_test-color-2_test-color-3.jpg").should be_true
    end
```

The `MasterAsset` class uses paperclip (requirement) to upload the image being processed to S3.

The error I get back is:

```
AWS::Errors::Base:
 # (eval):3:in `head_object'
```

which is an error in the interface between paperclip and aws-s3.

I've been troubleshooting, googling for a few hours now. It seems like it should be a very common situation but I can't seem to get the test to pass a second time.

Comment: If you delete the cassette, does that make the test pass again? Is that what you mean by 'second time'?

Comment: yeah, exactly. When the cassette does not already exist, the test passses. IFF the cassette exists, the test fails.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bug in either VCR or the underlying library VCR is hooking into (e.g. WebMock).

Can you file an [issue on github](https://github.com/myronmarston/vcr/issues)?  I'll be happy to take a look.  I'll need more detail though:

- Full backtrace of your error
- Code snippet of your VCR configuration
- A small, isolated executable example demonstrating the error would be nice.

Comment: I don't remember seeing this issue on github.